# ¿como entrar al modo consola administrativa en un servidor wildfly por medio de docker?

Tags: docker

estoy trabajando con docker soy muy novato en esto , tengo un dockerfile donde pongo el usuario , expongo el puerto por defecto 9990 para el modo de consola y el wildfly abre en el 8080 , pero no puedo entrar a la consola de administración cuando pongo en el navegador localhost:9990

en esta imagen se muestra lo que tengo en mi dockerfile solo es una prueba por si encuentran fallas de seguridad aun no llego a esa parte:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

aqui se observa que cargo mi app y aparte que si esta escuchando en el puerto 9990 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esto es lo que tengo en el dockerfile

```
FROM jboss/wildfly:10.1.0.Final

ADD https://downloads.mariadb.com/Connectors/java/connector-java-1.5.9/mariadb-java-client-1.5.9.jar /opt/jboss/wildfly/modules/system/layers/base/org/mariadb/jdbc/main/
COPY librerias/module.xml /opt/jboss/wildfly/modules/system/layers/base/org/mariadb/jdbc/main/
ADD aplicacion/Aplicacion.war /opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/deployments/

RUN /opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/add-user.sh admin Admin#123 --silent

EXPOSE 9990

CMD ["/opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/standalone.sh", "-b", "0.0.0.0", "-bmanagement", "0.0.0.0"]
```

así ejecute el contenedor

```
docker run -it --name fichero -p 8080:8080 jboss/wildfly:10.1.0.Final
```

y así me aparece en el navegador de chrome
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: una cosa es el puerto que expone docker `9990` y otro es el que expone tu proyecto, puedes agregar el dockerfile o  por lo menos como llamas al docker para iniciarlo

Comment: ya edite mi la pregunta

Comment: te falta habilitar el puerto 9900 , intenta algo como `docker run -it --name fichero -p 8080:8080 -p 9900:9900 jboss/wildfly:10.1.0.Final`

Comment: listo ya quedo no mas que era el puerto 9990 y pusiste el 9900 pero entendí lo que me quisiste decir , muchas gracias por tu ayuda y tu tiempo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Al ejecutar el comando:

```
docker run -it --name fichero -p 8080:8080 jboss/wildfly:10.1.0.Final
```

Solo estas aperturando  el puerto 8080, lo que debes hacer es aperturar el otro puerto, debes agregar a tu comando algo como `-p 9990:9990` la instruccion quedaria de la siguiente forma:

```
docker run -it --name fichero -p 8080:8080 -p 9990:9990 jboss/wildfly:10.1.0.Final
```

Anexo ademas la documentacion del [docker de wildfly](https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/wildfly/), por si tienes algun otro problema

Comment: listo es que marque la otra por que la tuya no se podía, pero ya marque lo que editaste como correcto gracias

Answer (score 1):

La consola web se encuentra en:

```
http://localhost:9990/console
```

Recuerda buscar siempre en internet dudas como esta, pues te ahorraras tiempo. Toma un link que te puede ayudar para futuras dudas sobre wildfly.

https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Admin+Guide?_sscc=t#AdminGuide-WebManagementInterface

Comment: es que ya lo puse como me indicas y no aparece , y creo yo ejecute bien el dockerfile logro entrar como se ve en la imagen al wildfly con localhost:8080 pero a la consola web no

Comment: Que error te aparece en la url que te he indicado? como comentas, si aparece esta homepage  es que el docker se ha ejecutado bien.

Comment: ya edite mi la pregunta puse lo que tengo en el dockerfile y como ejecute el contenedor y lo que aparece en el navegador, en la home page entro a todos los links que vienen ahí como documentation menos ala consola , ya cree el usuario también